# Why don't reputation points go below 1?

Tags: discussion, reputation

The reputation points of users never go below 1, even if their first question receives a downvote. Further upvotes increases reputation points, but they do not cancel the reputation points loss caused by the downvote. What's the reason for this?

Comment: [Meta Stack Exchange: Why does reputation have a lower bound of 1?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2621/167646)

Comment: @simonzack but this one surely have http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2621/183757

Answer (score 25):

I can see a practical reason for it besides being nice to users.

**When people harm their account so much that they *feel* they've backed themselves into a corner, they just abandon the account and create a new one.**

If rep could be negative they'd ask a few bad questions, get a bunch of downvotes, and end up with -52 rep or whatever. Then what would they do? They could try posting better questions to increase their rep, maybe with the idea that down the road they'd ask for dissociation from their earlier terrible questions. However, they probably don't know about dissociation and it may or may not be granted. (I've been around a bit and *I* don't know how one is eligible for it.) As far as *they* see it, they've backed themselves into a corner. The easy solution is to dump the account and create a new one which will start with 1 rep. There are mechanisms to prevent people from just creating accounts over and over but AFAIK it takes a bit of churning through accounts before a block happens.

**By not having negative reputation we remove at least one incentive to abandon accounts.** Basically, people can recover from early stumbles without carrying the effects of the stumbles forever. (And again, yes there's dissociation but new users don't know about it.) The ban and rate-limiting algorithms are still there to prevent bad postings from an account from going on for too long. Actually, if I recall correctly, there's been a recent move away from bans and towards rate-limiting because bans would just push people to abandon their account and create a new one.

Answer (score 10):

It's just being nice. Not kicking someone while they are down, so to speak.

Although the rep can't go below 1, other penalties are still fair game, like question and answer bans.